# Dagger build fails with realm plugin, Cannot find symbol class DaggerApplicationComponent

Tags: android, realm, dagger-2, dagger, realm-mobile-platform

While setting up realm in project by following [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started) documentation.

below is my project level gradle :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    // Realm
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
}
```

app level gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

dependencies {
 final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.7'
....
    def daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    annotationProcessor daggerCompiler
    testAnnotationProcessor daggerCompiler
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor daggerCompiler

    compile  "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28' //Required by Dagger2


}
```

Comment: It's because you wrote `"com.google.dagger:dagger-compilr:$DAGGER_VERSION"` instead of `"com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"`... also, I tend to just use `apt` instead of `annotationProcessor`, not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: Sorry about the typo i am already using com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION can you suggest me apt dependency for annotationProcessor .

Comment: Anyways, you get `Cannot find symbol class DaggerApplicationComponent` if your Dagger configuration fails somewhere, typically. You should look at the exact error your console gives you at the end.

Comment: I think Dagger 2 swallow errors i am not getting specific error in this case.

Comment: It is working fine if i removed realm configuration.

Comment: You should have at least one class that extends RealmObject in your project.

Comment: Didn't worked please check logs at https://s13.postimg.org/9m01nw9pj/Screen_Shot_2016_10_24_at_6_34_13_PM.png

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most serious downsides of Dagger 2 - its error reporting is terrible. I regularly observe these kind of errors, and you can't understand a thing from that message.

The problem is that Dagger 2 pre-processor runs before `javac` compilation, and if the code couldn't be processed, then pre-processor fails without generating components implementations. To my best knowledge, the pre-processor doesn't report what error caused the failure. Then, when `javac` compilation executed it fails because it can't find the generated file, but it doesn't proceed to compilation of other files, therefore the only error you see is about missing Dagger component.

What I do in such cases is three stepped solution:

1. Review VCS history and visit all changed files. Since IDE compiles each file upon visit, I will see if any of them has compilation errors.
2. If #1 didn't help, I would try to incrementally remove Dagger 2 code from the project (commit beforehand!) and try to recompile on the way. When Dagger 2 is removed from problematic region, Dagger components will be generated and `javac` comilation will show you the actual errors.
3. If nothing else helps, I'm visiting all project files one-by-one. Have done it twice already, and it is a nightmare.

I know nothing about Realm, but since I see it uses its own plugin, you could start by changing the order of plugins appliance in `build.gradle`. Switch these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: Switching the "apply plugin" lines as suggested above allowed me to identify the underlying error in my case: a breaking change in Realm 2.x.

Comment: While switching these lines allowed me to identify the Realm error that was preventing Dagger from generating it's classes, after correcting the error I had to restore the ordering of the lines as it introduces other errors (Realm annotations are not processed).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off of Vasiliy's previous answer. I'm promoting my comments to his/her answer to make the solution that worked for me more visible.

As Vasiliy suggested, reversing these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

allowed the reporting of an underlying Realm error that was preventing Dagger from generating my application component class (in my case, a breaking change introduced in Realm 2.x).

After addressing this issue, with the reordered `apply plugin` lines I received this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XXX is not part of the schema for this Realm
```

By reordering the plugins, Realm annotations are not being processed as needed.  So the plugin lines must then be restored to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```